# Two laptops and two monitors

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, displayport, docking-station

I would like to put together a setup with two monitors and two laptops, where both laptops can extend their display to both screens, and where I can switch between laptops without having to change cables. Ideally, the laptops should be connected only via their respective USB-C / Thunderbolt port.

Here’s what I came up with, I’m hoping to get feedback if this will work:

Use two monitors with integrated docking stations (i.e. USB-C with power delivery, like the Dell P2423DE). Connect laptop 1 to the USB-C port of monitor 1 and laptop 2 to the USB-C port of monitor 2. Connect the DP output of monitor 1 to the DP input of monitor 2 and the DP output of monitor 2 to the DP input of monitor 1. Like this, I can connect laptop 1 --> monitor 1 --> monitor 2 (i.e. daisy chaining, both screens will be used with laptop 1) while laptop 2 still gets charged but is not in use, and vice versa if I change the monitor inputs accordingly (through their menu) to use laptop 2 with both screens. For input, I’ll use a cordless keyboard and mouse, which can connect to both laptops. See this [diagram showing the proposed setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3jTk.png).

I thinks this should give me what I am looking for, but please let me know of any pitfalls or reasons why this won't work!

Comment: You would need a KVM.  USB Type-C KVMs will not come cheap.  You won't be able to daisy chain two laptops together.

Comment: The two laptops won't be in one daisy chain, it will be more like two parallel daisy chains with one laptop each. I.e. Laptop 1 --> USB-C --> monitor 1 --> DP --> monitor 2 and independent from that, laptop 2 --> USB-C --> monitor 2 --> DP --> monitor 1. The question is, when it's not in use, will laptop 2's connection interfere with the laptop 1 daisy chain (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up buying two monitors with integrated USB-C docking stations in the end (Dell P2423DE). The setup that I suggested above does indeed work.

Comment: I have the same set up with the Dell U2723QE. In my display settings, I initially had just the 3 screens showing up. After a reboot, I am seeing another Dell monitor showing up as Monitor 4. Are you experiencing the same thing? Is it possible to share USB devices, say a web cam or microphone?

Comment: Have you tried the Dell Display Manager software?
I find that peripherals (thumb drives or the Dell sound bar) connect to the laptop that has its USB-C cable plugged into the particular monitor.

Comment: Hi @gandi2223, I'm looking into doing the same thing as you did, also with two P2423DE. Is Power Delivery and ethernet always active for both laptops, regardless of which laptop is currently set as input for the displays? Anything else that you think one should know before buying the setup? Thank you!!

Comment: Hi @janoliver - power delivery works for both laptops in parallel. My router isn't close to my desk, that's why I am not using the Ethernet ports, hence I cannot answer the 2nd part of your question.
I am very happy with the setup.
I tried to come up with a way to switch between inputs for both screens with a keyboard shortcut, using AutoHotkey and Dell Display Manager, but it doesn't work reliably. If anyone has a good solution for this, please let me know!